# Truezip returning unsupported compression method error when extracting large files

Tags: truezip

Truezip 6 and 7 returning error message "compression method 9 is not supported" when extracting any files greater then 2GB that were compressed using windows compressing method.
(This is achieve by highlighting the file that is 2GB or bigger and then right clicking on the mouse -> send to->Compressed (zipped) folder).

### using Truezip 7 code below:

TFile srcFile = new TFile(src, incPath);
  TFile dstFile = new TFile(dst);

### TFile.cp_rp(srcFile, dstFile, TArchiveDetector.NULL);

produces the error "compression method 9 is not supported" when it hits the "..truezip.zip.RawZipFile.getInputStream". Is there a way to fix this? or a method to overcome this issue? 
This only happens when using windows zipped method, however when using 7Zip to compress files that is greater then 2GB and then using truezip to extract isn't a problem.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 and JRE 7.

Answer (score 0):

Method 9 is an extended Deflater method with a bigger dictionary. As the exception says, it isn't supported because the JRE doesn't support it. It seems to be new that the Windows Explorer is using this method.

Comment: Even the latest JRE? Is there going to be a work around or is there a work around for this new method from windows?

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans to add support for this variant of the Deflater method. In general, the ZIP File Format Specification is very broad and almost any implementation is only a sub-set - TrueZIP/TrueVFS is no exception.